# Find the general solution of $\sin(4t) + \sqrt3 \cos(4t)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How to find the general solution of the equation $\sin 4t + \sqrt{3} \cos 4t$ in exact form.

so what I know is $\sin 4t + \sqrt3 \cos 4t = 2 \cos(4t - \frac{\pi}{3})$

The answer is $t = \frac{\pi}{12} (3n-1)$

What to do next?

Comment: I suppose you want the expression to be zero ? If this is the case, please edit

Comment: Based on the solution I guess the expression must be equal to $1$ or $-1$ ?

Comment: *What* equation? $\sin 4t+\sqrt3\cos 4t=0$ or $\sin 4t+\sqrt3\cos 4t=\cdots$?

Comment: Hint: Do you know the $\tan$ function and its inverse $\arctan$?

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question...

Answer (score 3):

We're given (I think...)

$$\sin 4t+\sqrt3\cos 4t=2\cos\left(4t-\frac\pi3\right)=2\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos 4t+\frac12\sin4t\right)=\sqrt3\cos 4t+\sin 4t\implies$$

And as I see it this is an identity...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to solve $\sin 4t + \sqrt{3} \cos 4t=0. \;$ Divide by the cos term and get $\tan 4t = -\sqrt{3}\;$ with the specific solution $t_0 = \frac{1}{4}\arctan(-\sqrt{3}) =  -\frac{\pi}{12}.\;$ Since $\tan 4t\,$ has the period $\frac{\pi}{4},\,$ the general solution is
$t = t_0 + n\frac{\pi}{4} = -\frac{\pi}{12} + n\frac{\pi}{4} =  \frac{\pi}{12} (3n-1).$

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret $\sin 4t + \sqrt{3} \cos 4t$ as a inner product: $\langle (\sin 4t,  \cos 4t), (1,\sqrt{3})\rangle$ and so the solutions of $\sin 4t + \sqrt{3} \cos 4t=0$ correspond to the vectors $(\sin 4t,  \cos 4t)$ that are orthogonal to $(1,\sqrt{3})$. This gives you two possible angles for $(\sin 4t,  \cos 4t)$, from which you can find $t$. Draw a picture.